# Custom static error pages with WSGI Apache site?

Tags: apache-2.2

How do you configure Apache to server a static error page for a WSGI site?

I see a lot of answers for this, [like this one](https://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-page-for-when-tomcat-is-down-for-maintenance.html) that suggest doing simply:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance-message.html
```

But this doesn't work if you use a custom site. The Apache "document root directory" doesn't exist with WSGI.

How do you tell Apache to skip the WSGI site and serve a static file?